# jQuery plugin to populate form controls from a JSON response?

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, populate

Is there any plugin to populate any form control from JSON data with one command?

I have a form with many selects, checkboxes and radiobuttons in it. Almost all controls depend on each other (many dependencies). Which way will be the shortest to describe all relations with controls?

Example: Form to choose travel package contains controls:

- countries
- regions
- hotels
- stars
- nights
- etc.

Mostly all controls should be updated .onChange of other controls (when choose 5*/4* hotel will update list of countries, regions, nights, etc.)

I am looking for solution to

1. easy describe relations
2. easy populate updated values of controls

Answer (score 0):

I think the best plugin for your work is Jquery.Populate():
http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html